# HTML aside is hiding my js nav bar

Tags: php, javascript, html

I'm working on my own personal site [here](http://billcaffery.dnsd.me). If you hover over any of the nav bar elements you will notice there is some flicker and not all of the elements are visible. You can verify this via `F12`. It seems to me that the `<aside>` tag is "hiding" the info I'm looking for.

Would someone please tell me how to bring the nav bar to the front of something. I'm not really sure what's going on here.

**`index.php`**:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
        <title>Grown Kidd Creations</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <img alt="Picture of me and Cian" src="img/caindaddysleepin.jpeg" title="Cian and Daddy">
            <?include_once 'nav/nav.php';?>
        </header>
        <aside class="left"><p>No idea what to put here. how about you fill out the form and tell me?</p></aside>

        <aside class="right">
            Recent News/Updates:<br/>
            <span class="undercon">This will be updated soon with links and maybe a blog.</span>
            <ul>
                <li>Cian</li>
                <li>Work</li>
                <li>Family</li>
            </ul>
        </aside>
        <footer>
            Send me some love at <a href="mailto:billythakidd04@gmail.com">BillyThaKidd04@gmail.com</a><br/>
            Or find me at:<br/>
            <div class="g-plus" data-href="https://plus.google.com/109325835178774768962?prsrc=3" data-theme="dark" rel="author"></div>
            <a href="https://twitter.com/ThaKidd04" class="twitter-follow-button" data-show-count="false" data-size="large">Follow @ThaKidd04</a>
<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>
        </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

**`nav.php`**

```
<?//navigation bar?>
<script>
    var el = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
    el.className = "";
</script>
<noscript>
<!--[if IE]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="nav/css/ie.css">
<![endif]-->
</noscript>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="nav/css/nav.css">
    <!--[if IE]>
        <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <nav id="topNav" class="no-js">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.php" title="Home">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" title="Projects">Projects</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="" title="Personal Projects">Personal Projects</a></li>
                    <li><a href="" title="Work Projects">Work Projects</a></li>
                    <li class="last"><a href="pages/sitepage.php" target="new" title="About this site">This Site</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="contactme.php" title="Contact Me">Contact Me</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="http://www.facebook.com/BillyThaKidd" target="new" title="FaceBook">FaceBook</a></li>
                    <li><a href="" target="new" title="Google Plus">Google +</a></li>
                    <li><a href="" target="new" title="LinkedIn">LinkedIn</a></li>
                    <li class="last"><a href="" title="Email Me">Email Me</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="/pages/viewblog.php" title="About Me">About Me</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="/pages/viewblog.php">Blog</a></li>
                    <li><a href="" title="Resume">Resume</a></li>
                    <li class="last"><a target="new" href="https://github.com/billythakidd04" title="GitHub">GitHub</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <script src="nav/js/modernizr.custom.69568.js"></script>
    <script>
        (function($)
        {
            //cache nav
            var nav = $("#topNav");

            //add indicators and hovers to submenu parents
            nav.find("li").each(function()
            {
                if ($(this).find("ul").length > 0)
                {
                    $("<span>").text("").appendTo($(this).children(":first"));

                    //show subnav on hover
                    $(this).mouseenter(function()
                    {
                        $(this).find("ul").stop(true, true).slideDown();
                    });

                    //hide submenus on exit
                    $(this).mouseleave(function()
                    {
                        $(this).find("ul").stop(true, true).slideUp();
                    });
                }
            });
        })(jQuery);
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should post your `css` since it seems that the whole issue is connected—or at least can be solved—by a [`z-index`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/z-index) adjustment:

> The z-index CSS property specifies the z-order of an element and its
>   descendants. When elements overlap, z-order determines which one
>   covers the other. An element with a larger z-index generally covers an
>   element with a lower one.

Comment: ^^ this guy FTW!! Perfect answer/solution I added `nav
{
 z-index: 1;
}

:not nav
{
 z-index: 0;
}` and it worked perfectly.